# Image and Video slider Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Are there any ways to show Images and Videos on the same slider on android studio? The last I heard of such services was the MediaSliderView (https://github.com/Zeuskartik/MediaSliderView). However, they are since depreciated. Are there any alternatives?